# update 2 times a same column in 1 query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In may table 'Customer' the column StartDate can have 2 different values:

```
'25.02.2015 - 31.03.2015 ;  -  ;  -  ;  - '

' -  ;  -  ;  -  ;  - '
```

I want to update this column in order to remove empty dates, i.e

```
'  -  ;  -  ;  - '
```

In an update query we can not put the same column more than one time, like in the following query:

```
update Customer
set StartDate= replace(StartDate,' -  ;  -  ;  -  ;  - ',''),
StartDate= replace(StartDate,' ;  -  ;  -  ;  - ','')
```

I want to avoid 2 update query to do this. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Once you figure this out I would highly recommend you stop storing dates in text columns. Not only are you using the wrong datatype you are storing two values in a single intersection.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed replace functions:

```
UPDATE  Customer
SET     StartDate = REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(StartDate, ' -  ;  -  ;  -  ;  - ', ''),
                            ' ;  -  ;  -  ;  - ', '')
```